# How can I make my source wait until button release before continuing?

Tags: c, wiringpi

If I press button 1 it will spam my screen saying it was pressed, I want it to wait until released before it does anything else, similar to a toggle but not a toggle.

I've tried adding a delay before, but that doesn't quite do exactly what I need... I want it to wait until released, instead of wait a hard set amount of time

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>

int main(void) {
    wiringPiSetupGpio();
    while(1) {
        if(!digitalRead(8) && digitalRead(7)) {
            printf("Button-1 pressed\n");
        }
        if(!digitalRead(7) && digitalRead(8)) {
            printf("Button-2 pressed\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Expected outcome:

```
Button-1 pressed
```

Actual outcome:

```
Button-1 pressed
Button-1 pressed
Button-1 pressed
Button-1 pressed
Button-1 pressed
Button-1 pressed
etc...
```

Comment: Isn't there an interrupt to signal a release?

Comment: Assuming you have no hardware filters, the first thing you need to do is handling signal de-bouncing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to program this behavior by yourself.

```
int sevenDown = 0;
while(1) {
    if(!sevenDown && digitalRead(7)) {
        sevenDown = 1\n");
    }
    if(sevenDown && !digitalRead(7)) {
        printf("Button-1 pressed\n");
        sevenDown = 0;
    }
}
```